# How to change HirerachicalDataTemplate associated with the WPF TreeView programatically at run time?

Tags: wpf, treeview, wpf-controls

I have a TreeView control on my WPF window. I am giving only relevant XAML from my window.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="HierarchicalTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding SubOrgUnitItems}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="16" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" Width="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrgUnitName}" Name="treeText" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>



<TreeView Margin="10,35,10,10" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      IsTabStop="True" Name="orgTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource HierarchicalTemplate}" TabIndex="700" SelectedItemChanged="orgTreeView_SelectedItemChanged" />
```

When the Collection of Organisations is bound to `DataContext` of the `TreeView`, items are displayed with the `OrgUnitName`'s value as a text at every node. 
Now at  run time I want to see some other property's value as a text at every node. e.g. `OrgUnitCode` instead of `OrgUnitName`. Both are properties declared in the view model class associated with the treeview.

How can i do it programatically at run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `HierarchicalDataTemplateSelector`.

Define two different `HierarchicalDataTemplate` (as you did).

Inherite your custom selector class from `DataTemplateSelector`, override its SelectTemplate method and put there the logic of the selection. This method will return the correct template in each case.

Create a Resource(Custom Selector class) in the xaml file.

Set the `TreeView`s `ItemTemplateSelector` to the static selector resource.

See a simple example here: [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2bd054fe-2fb6-47ed-be8f-26545c07e655/)

Comment: Accepting as an answer. Thanks ! :) Do you have any idea if we can modify the existing `HierarchicalDataTemplate` at run time? e.g. Modify the `Binding` property of the `TextBlock` declared in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` XAML resource.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved what I wanted to do, but unfortunately by some work around. Following thing worked for me but it may not be the correct answer to the problem.

I added one more `HirerachicalDataTemplate` and `TreeView`. The new template uses the `OrgUnitCode` property. The new tree view uses the new template.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="HierarchicalTemplateUsingCode" ItemsSource="{Binding SubOrgUnitItems}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="16" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" Width="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrgUnitCode}" Name="treeText" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>



<TreeView Margin="10,35,10,10" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      IsTabStop="True" Name="orgTreeViewCode" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource HierarchicalTemplateUsingCode}" TabIndex="700" SelectedItemChanged="orgTreeViewCode_SelectedItemChanged"  Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

At run time, when I want to see `OrgUnitCode` property value as a text at the node, I simply make new tree visible and hide the first one (mentioned in question). So making tree views visible/invisible help me to achieve what I wanted to do.